# C++ execute temp file as bash script

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, bash, shell

I have a program that needs to run a program we'll call externalProg in parallel on our linux (CentOS) cluster - or rather, it needs to run many instances of externalProg, each on different cores. Each "thread" creates 3 files based on a few parameters - the inputs to externalProg, a command file to tell externalProg how to execute my file, and a bash script to set up the environment (calls a setup script provided by the manufacturer) and actually call externalProg with my inputs.

Since this needs to be parallel with an unknown number of concurrent threads and I don't want to risk overwriting another thread's files, I am creating temp files using

```
mkstemp("PREFIX_XXXXXX")
```

for these input files. After the external program runs, I extract the relevant data and store it, and close the temp files (therefore deleting them).

We'll call the files created (Which actually have a name based on the template above)

```
tmpInputs - Inputs to externalProg
tmpCommand - Input that tells externalProg how to execute tmpInputs
tmpBash - bash script to set up and call externalProg with my inputs
```

The file tmpBash looks something like

```
source /path/to/setup/script # Sets up environment variables
externalProg < /path/to/tmpCommand
```

where tmpCommand is just a simple text file.

The problem I'm having is actually executing the bash script. Within my program, I call

```
ostringstream launchcmd;
launchcmd << "bash " << path_to_tmpBash
system(launchcmd.str().c_str());
```

But nothing happens. No error, no warning, no 'file not found' or permission denied or anything. I have verified that the files are being created and have the correct content. The rest of the code after system() is executed successfully (Though it fails since externalProg wasn't run).

Strangely, if I go back to the terminal and type

```
bash /path/to/tmpBash
```

then externalProg is executed successfully. I have also cout'd the launchcmd string, copy and pasted that in to the terminal, which also works successfully. For some reason, this only fails when called within my program.

After a bit of experimentation, I've determined that system() calls /bin/sh on our cluster. If I change launchcmd to look like

```
/path/to/tmpBash
```

(So that the full command should look like /bin/sh /path/to/tmpBash), I get a permission denied error, which is no surprise. The problem is that I can't chmod +x the tmpBash file while it's still open, and if I close the file, it gets deleted - so I'm not sure how to address that.

Is there something obviously wrong I'm doing, or does system() have some nuance that I'm missing?

edit: I wanted to add that I can successfully call things like

```
system("echo $PATH")
```

and get the expected results (in this case, my default $PATH).

Comment: `ofstream launchcmd;` Did you mean [`ostringstream launchcmd;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)? (Just because you're stating you want to use `system(launchcmd.str().c_str());`)

Comment: I did mean ostringstream! I've edited my question to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two separate ideas:

- Change your `SHELL` environment variable to be `/bin/bash`, then call `system()`,

or:

- Use [execve directly](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ENV04-CPP.+Do+not+call+system()+if+you+do+not+need+a+command+processor) `execve('/bin/bash', ['/path/to/tmpBash'], environ)

Comment: I checked, and $SHELL is already /bin/bash.

I'm working on trying execve or execv, but I'm still having the same problem as before, oddly.

Comment: @user3741834: can you give me some functional example code to play with? I'd be happy to fix it from a starting point, but I don't want to write it out from scratch.

Comment: One second here. I can't directly paste my code (security issue), but I'm working up an example that recreates the problem.

Comment: Huh. I think I may have inadvertently found the problem. It looks like bash will fail (apparently silently if called by system()) if the input file is held open by another process. I never found it in my other tests as the files were all closed by that time, so it worked in those cases. I rearranged things so that the file handles are closed, just not unlink()'d, and it's now working. I've marked your answer as the solution in case anybody else finds this question. Thank you!